# Resize to size less than setContentMinSize:

Tags: window-manager

It is extremely annoying when some apps set the minimal size of their window too big. Ie. viber window is huge and should be very small considering occasionally arriving messages (there are a lot of examples of this behaviour).

Is there any way to explore this parameter -  setContentMinSize: and change it? Let's say via xcode or any other means??

Many thanks for any help.

Comment: Unless an app is open-source, you can't access the app's code to modify it yourself because that would open up an app to code-stealing and `setContentMinSize` is set right in the `.m` or `.swift` files of the app itself along with all of its important and potentially proprietary code.

Comment: @owlswipe Let's say the app is open source - how can I explore its content and modify this parameter?

Comment: Find its source code (probably on Github or their own site), download it, open it in Xcode, change it to your heart's content (if you get to this step, just ask and I can help you find the `setContentMinSize` call), and build + run it on your computer.

Comment: Do note that you can edit some of the resources and the plist of an app by two-finger clicking on it in Finder -> Applications and then hitting `Show Package Contents`, but unless the developer put `setContentMinSize` in a user-accessible file, you can't change it from its package contents. You can, however, do things like change the app's dock icon from here.